# Don't know how to read a sp from vb.net 2013

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-server-express

I have a stored procedure which returns variable columns as a table. I need to put this output in a `DataGridView`. Can anyone help me?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express and Visual basic 2013 on windows 8.1

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Pivot] 
   @Dias varchar(4),
   @Rubro varchar(1)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @Cols += STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Linea) FROM TablaByModel WHERE 
           Rubro = @Rubro FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
SELECT @Query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT [AAAAMM] AS [AAAAMM], [Linea] AS [Linea], 
           ' + @Dias  +    ' as [Dias] FROM [TablaByModel] o ) AS t 
           PIVOT
           (AVG(Dias) FOR Linea IN( ' + @cols + ' )' + ' ) AS p ; ';

    EXECUTE(@Query);
 END
```

The output is like this:

```
    AAAAMM    A78   A79P    Plus     TC     TC2
    --------------------------------------------
    201010                   7  
    201104            90            
    201105                   94 
    201106           43       46      41     38 
    201107           34       35      35     32 
    201108           14       11      11     16 
    201109           43       10      12     119    
    201110     155   10       12       9      6 
    201111           23       37      15     10 
    201112           34       26      13     23
```

Name columns may vary.

The VB code I'm trying to use is:

```
'    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=server\sqlexpress;Initial   Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True")
'    Dim p As SqlClient.SqlParameter
'    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SP_Pivot", con, Nothing)
'    Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
'    Dim table As New DataTable
'    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
'    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

'    con.Open()
'    'Fill the parameters
'    p = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dias", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4)
'    p.Value = "Dias"
'    p = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rubro", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)
'    p.Value = "H"

'    'Assign the select command
'    adapter.Selectcommand = cmd

'    'Fill the datatable
'    Try
'    '    adapter.Fill(table)
'        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
'    Catch ex As System.Exception
'        MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException.Message)
'    End Try


'    'DataGridView1.DataSource = reader

'    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem this way:
    Dim bla bla
    Parameters ...

```
     Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim NroReg As Integer = myReader.FieldCount - 1
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(myReader)

        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
    Finally
        If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you should pass the `DataGridView1.DataSource` a `DataTable`, yet you pass it the `SqlDataReader` from `cmd.ExecuteReader()`.  Look at the documentation for [`DataGridView.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see what it accepts.

Anyways, what you need to do is set `DataSource` to `table` after `adapter.Fill(table)` has been invoked.

Comment: I can't do a Fill method or don't know how to do it. The tableadapter when generate don't create this method and don't let me create one. Sorry for my english.

Comment: You already call it:
    'Fill the datatable
    Try
        adapter.Fill(table)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException.Message)
    End Try

Comment: I use the assistant to create a DataSource and select the sp, when I use the preview data I can see the table. but when I use the code I can't see anything. I don't know another way to see it.